# scale image by scaling rectangle without group fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am new in fabric.js and want to achieve one functionality
I added image and one rectangle same size of image, now I want to scale image while scaling rectangle.
I don't want to group objects , image should scale by scaling rectangle with previous left, top position of image

below is my code

```js
var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var pug;
var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 50,
        top: 70,
        scaleX: .25,
        scaleY: .25,
        selectable: false
    });
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 65,
      left: 200,
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      fill: 'red',
    });
    canvas.sendToBack(rect);
    canvas.bringToFront(pug);
    
    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.add(pug);
    canvas.renderAll();
    
};
pugImg.src = imgURL; 
canvas.on('object:scaling', function(e) {
  var bounds = e.target.getBoundingRect();
  pug.set({
    width: bounds.width,
    height: bounds.height,
    top: bounds.top,
    left: bounds.left
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.2.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I added image and one rectangle same size of image

In your example the rectangle is not the same size as the image

```
rect = {
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  scaleX: 1,
  scaleY: 1,
}
pug = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    scaleX: .25,
    scaleY: .25
});
```

To achieve the desired effect, you need to give theme the same (width, height, scaleX, scaleY), then just copy the `rect` (scaleX, scaleY) to the pug. otherwise
if they're not the same size you'll need to compute the scale ratio between the two.

```js
var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var pug, rect;
var pugImg = new Image();
pugImg.onload = function (img) {    
    pug = new fabric.Image(pugImg, {
        angle: 0,
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        left: 50,
        top: 70,
        scaleX: .25,
        scaleY: .25,
        selectable: false
    });
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
      top: 65,
      left: 200,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      scaleX: .25,
      scaleY: .25,
      fill: 'red',
    });
    canvas.sendToBack(rect);
    canvas.bringToFront(pug);
    
    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.add(pug);
    canvas.renderAll();
    
};
pugImg.src = imgURL; 
canvas.on('object:scaling', function(e) {
  pug.set({
    scaleX: rect.scaleX,
    scaleY: rect.scaleY,
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.2.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```